# Alternative for Spring-security-saml2-core dependency as it have valnerable

Tags: saml-2.0, query-by-example

I am resolving SSDLC findings and I figure out that Spring-security-saml2-core:1.0.5 dependency having some vulnerability. I want to replace this dependency in build.gradle . Also I need to change in code to avoid the related class and interface implementation. If any one have any suggestion please let me know with one example.

Need a alternative for SAML2 as it causing valnerability.